# Showing ${\sum_{i=0}^n (2i+1)}=(n+1)^2$ (and generally simplifying $\sum P(i)$ for polynomial $P$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Asking WolframAlpha to solve $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^n (2i+1)}$ the answer is $(n+1)^2$.

I wonder if there is a way to prove it or, more generally, which general strategy should be used to compute $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^n P(i)}$ for some given polynomial $P(i)$.

Is it enough linearity and Gauss' identity
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(2i+1)=2\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i + \sum\limits_{i=0}^n1 = 2\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=(n+1)^2$

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n (2i +1) = \sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)^2 - i^2$, which is telescoping

Comment: What general strategy?  Linearity of summation... that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n(\alpha A(i)+\beta B(i))=\alpha \sum\limits_{i=0}^n A(i) + \beta\sum\limits_{i=0}^nB(i)$, from which you can use what you already know about $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^k$ and handle each power separately

Comment: A general proof of a closed form may use linearity, binomial coeficients an [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)

Comment: Thanks, I was in trouble interpreting $\sum_i 1$ since, from linearity, every constant passes out from the sum, and there would be nothing left to sum.

Comment: @ric.san $\sum_i 1$ could be interpreted as $\sum_i f(i)$ where $f(i)=1$ This is a constant function and we end up adding 1 all the times

Comment: Yeah, I never thought that $a*b$ could equivalently be seen  as $a*\sum_{i=1}^b 1$ or viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments,
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n (2i+1)=2\sum_{i=0}^n i+\sum_{i=0}^n1 = n(n+1)+n+1=(n+1)^2 $$
There is a general formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n i^k$ which is [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) :
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i^k=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j}B_jn^{k+1-j} $$
where $B_j$ is the $j$-th Bernoulli number. Since for any polynomial $P\neq 0$,
$$ P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\deg P}\frac{P^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k $$
we have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n P(i)=\sum_{k=0}^{\deg P}\frac{P^{(k)}(0)}{(k+1)!}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+1}{j}B_jn^{k+1-j} $$
I'm not sure it is any easier in the end, or even useful.

**However**, what you can do in practice is to decompose the sum :
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n P(i)=a_p\sum_{i=0}^n i^p+\ldots+a_0\sum_{i=0}^n 1 $$
for $P=\sum_{i=0}^p a_iX^i$, then you compute $\sum_{i=0}^p i^k$ for all $k\leqslant p$ hoping it is not too boring (it is not for small values of $k$). In order to do this, you can say that
$$ \int_i^{i+1}x^k dx=\frac{(i+1)^{k+1}-i^{k+1}}{k+1}=i^k+Q(i) ​$$
where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k-1$, therefore
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n i^k=\int_0^{n+1}x^kdx-\sum_{i=0}^n Q(i)=\frac{(n+1)^{k+1}-1}{k+1}-\sum_{i=0}^n Q(i) $$
and you can compute the last sum using the expression you've found for $\sum_{i=0}^n 1,\ldots,\sum_{i=0}^n i^{k-1}$. This way, you can successively compute $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$, $\sum_{i=0}^n i^3$,etc...